# networkx: how to control node postion on graphs

Tags: position, nodes, networkx, draw

In order to draw a graph I have defined the pos as a dictionary:

```
pos={'0025': (0, 0), '0023': (400, 0), '0028': (800, 0), '0029': (1200, 0), '0045': (1600, 0), '0057': (2000, 0), '0062': (2400, 0), '0083': (2800, 0), '0107': (3200, 0), '0111': (3600, 0), '0141': (4000, 0), '0144': (4400, 0), '0026': (800.0, 1), '0050': (1200.0, 1), '0115': (2600.0, 1)}
```

But I do not get the nodes represented where I expected:
[image: Nodes representation]
Notice that the relative position is OK but the scale is not right. Probably I am misunderstanding something.

Here is the code I wrote to draw the graph:

```
def draw_G_msn_tr(self):
    pos={'0025': (0, 0), '0023': (400, 0), '0028': (800, 0), '0029': (1200, 0), '0045': (1600, 0), '0057': (2000, 0), '0062': (2400, 0), '0083': (2800, 0), '0107': (3200, 0), '0111': (3600, 0), '0141': (4000, 0), '0144': (4400, 0), '0026': (800.0, 1), '0050': (1200.0, 1), '0115': (2600.0, 1)}      
    nx.draw(self.G_msn_tr,pos=pos, node_color=self.node_colors, with_labels=True, node_size=900)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()
```

I need more space between nodes in order to show edge labels

Thank you in advance for your support.
BR.

Comment: `networkx` is rather peculiar in as much that the node positions and node sizes are given with respect to completely different coordinate systems. Node positions are in data coordinates, node sizes are given in axis coordinates (IIRC - might also be display coordinates). [Here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) is a matplotlib tutorial explaining the concepts. Hence specifying a node size of 900 does not mean that the node will have a diameter or radius of 900, 450, or 30 in data coordinates (any of which would make sense).

Comment: You are basically left with three options: 1) play around with the node sizes / spacing until the graph is good enough, or 2) do the transformations manually as laid out in the linked tutorial above. Option 3 (warning: shameless plug) is using my [`netgraph` package](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph), which is a fork of the networkx drawing utilities in which all elements are expressed in data coordinates. Bonus: I autoscale the text font such that the text box fits into the node elements.